# MongoRepository findByThisAndThat custom @Query with multiple parameters

Tags: mongodb, spring-boot, mongodb-query, spring-data

I am trying to run this query

```
{campaignId: ObjectId('5a6b11e806f0252e1408e379'),'options.path': 'NT'}
```

it works perfectly in Compass, but when I try to add in MongoRepository interface like below:

```
@Query("{ 'campaignId': ObjectId(?0), 'options.path': ?1})")
public Dialog findByCampaignIdAndPath(String campaignId, String path);
```

I get this exception:

> nested exception is com.mongodb.util.JSONParseException:
>   @Query("{ 'campaignId': ObjectId(?0), 'options.path': ?1})")

Using spring-boot version **1.5.9.RELEASE**, not the buggy [version](http://forum.spring.io/forum/spring-projects/data/nosql/101818-mongorepository-json-query-parse-exception)

EDIT1: specified the exact id name, as suggested in comments

EDIT2: Here is my Dialog class

```
@Getter     
@Setter
@Document(collection = "Dialog")
public class Dialog {
    @Id
    public String id;
    private DBRef campaignId;
    private Message message;
    private List<Option> options;

    public Dialog(final Message message, final List<Option> options) {
        this.message = message;
        this.options = options;
    }
}
```

Comment: if you are specifying the id then what is the need for specifying any other query parameters? isn't it redundant

Comment: you are right, actually let me re-phrase its not the id, its supposed to be a manual ref id of a document in another collection

Comment: show code for Dialog class

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Try this:

```
@Query("{ 'campaignId': ?0, 'options.path': ?1}")
public Dialog findByIdAndPath(String id, String path);
```

Or Simply:

```
public Dialog findByCampaignIdAndOptionsPath(String id, String path);
```

If `Option` is an embedded document

Comment: @shabby check updated answer, or add code for Dialog class.

Comment: added the Dialog class, but it doesnt return any result, although the JSON parse exception is gone

Comment: It should be `findByCampaignIdAndOptions_Path`

Comment: @pvpkiran Check this, it show how to find by fields of embedded documents: https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#repositories.query-methods.query-property-expressions

Comment: @shabby In your Dialog, campaignId is an object of DBRef. Why not it should be a simple String object?? Or there is any other info in this object?

Comment: @Afridi I am also not sure, the document in the collection has campaignId type as ObjectId, I am unable to map it in here through String, dont know which type to keep, any suggestions on that?

Comment: @shabby what is "campaignId"? Is it referring to any object/collection?? if yes, then you can do it like
@DBRef(db = your_collection_name)
private Campaign campaignId;
Or you can also set as String. Its totally depend on your usage.